# Pests tag too general?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [pests](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pests) tag is proving popular but i'm tempted to retag/encourage more detailed tags.

[ants](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ants), [mice](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mice), [birds](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds) are all interesting and very different in the kinds of problems they generate, how to combat etc.

Then [pests](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pests) would mainly be for cases where questioner isn't sure what's attacking his plant.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

That's a good idea, but I don't think anyone is ever going to get a gold badge in [cutworm](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cutworm) that way.

Could we keep both tags?

For instance:

[birds](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds) + [pests](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pests) + [sunflowers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunflowers) means how to get rid of bad birds eating your sunflowers.

But,

[birds](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds) + [birdseed](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birdseed) + [sunflowers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunflowers) means how to attract birds to your garden to eat your sunflowers or how to choose sunflowers birds you like will eat.

Comment: +1 -- but I'm itching for a gold badge in [tag:slugs]